# Maven EAR compiling

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have this dependency (and many others like this) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jShrink</groupId>
    <artifactId>jShrink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../kladr-ear/lib/jShrink-3.0.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

So how to add this JAR to EAR/LIB folder with MAVEN while package?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the available Maven [scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope), I would expect you to mark this as

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

and upload the jar file to your repository (local or remote). Maven should give you the appropriate command line to perform that upload.

EDIT: As noted below, this scope is the *default*, and as such you could omit it.

Comment: So if I will need to package this project on another computer I need to upload this jars to repo again?

Comment: By the way as I noticed, maven adding jar to EAR/LIB folder only if they dont have any scope...

Comment: you don't need <scope>compile</scope>, it's the default when unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies going into the EAR should generally be based on he dependencies needed for EJB modules. If you have an EJB module with library X on compile scope then that will trigger Maven to want to package the library in the ear that the EJB is part of. No need to manage any scopes at all in the ear pom.

If you don't have any EJBs and only WARs, I would not package libraries in the EAR but simply deploy them as part of the WAR (so they end up in WEB-INF/lib). Keep the web dependencies nice and contained per module, even if that means you get duplicates.

Also compile is the default scope, so you don't ever need to manually declare it unless you're doing it to override another scope set for the dependency.